# why do spans overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a cell that contains two spans, the first containing a span and and input. I want these to overlap (I use them to create an edit-in-place). So I set the parent span positioning to relative and set their position to absolute with left: 0. When I do that, the second top span also moves to the left of the cell. Why? How to fix (I want the inner span and input to overlap)

UPDATE: Note that the input is used for edit-in-place, so the other span needs to be positioned after it. Otherwise, when I remove the visibility style (by toggling a class), then it will overwrite the second span. I've updated the fiddle, so it shows bot the span and the input.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvyLtr82/5/

Here's the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="first">
                    <span>hi</span>
                    <input value="hi"/>
                </span>
                <span> there</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
    position:relative;
}

.first > * {
    position: absolute;
}
.first > span {

    left: 0;
}

.first > input {
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: just removes .first property in your css

Comment: @NandhaKumar: this means that the input is no longer overlapping its sibling span.

Comment: you want output as one time span hi and span there and next time input hi and span there, am i correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to enter data in the input field, try below

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="first">
                    <span onclick='$(this).hide().next().show()'>hi</span>
                    <input value="hi" onclick='$(this).hide().prev().show()'/>
                </span>
                <span>there</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.first >input {  
   display: none;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/jvyLtr82/8/

If you want to enter data in input field, try below

HtML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="first">
                    <span onclick='$(this).next().toggle().next().toggle()'>switch</span>
                    <span >hi</span>
                    <input value="hi"/>
                </span>
                <span>there</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.first >input {  
   display: none;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jvyLtr82/10/

Comment: But then, when the input is visible, 'there' is pushed, so in a table it means all columns will get wider. This is why i use visibility (to preserve space when the input is not visible) and need the positioning

Comment: @IttayD understand,try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jvyLtr82/11/ it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Because both span and input are absolutely positioned there is nothing to add to parent span width. Make only input positioned absolute and in edit mode make span hidden and input visible:

```
.first {
    position:relative;
}
.first > input {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.first.edit > span {
    display: none;
}
.first.edit > input {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jvyLtr82/7/

Comment: Yes, but then the 'there' span isn't positioned after the input. so when i toggle visibility, i'll have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do :

```
.first {
    position:relative;
}

.first > * {
    position: relative;
}
.first > span {

    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The input is positions after first>span

Comment: You want the first to overlap first>span?